# How do I set my Kendo DataSource up to handle this specific data?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do I set up my Kendo DataSource given the following data:

```
{"Data":
   [{"PSA_Comments_Num":177,"Comment":"wtf","EnteredByEmployee":"Carlos Mendieta","EnteredDate":"\/Date(1397496581900)\/"},
    {"PSA_Comments_Num":178,"Comment":"work damn it","EnteredByEmployee":"Carlos Mendieta","EnteredDate":"\/Date(1397496587273)\/"}],
    "Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,
    "Errors":null}
```

I've tried something like this to no avail:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {                                                     
                        return data.Data;  // The problem is in this line i'm sure.
                    }

                }
            });
```

but keep getting "Error: Unable to get value of the property 'slice': object is null or undefined"

Comment: It looks like the Array you are wanting to bind to is called simply "Data" in that JSON.  So try "return data.Data;" ?

Comment: Thanks man.  That's actually how I got the error. Apologies, I will edit the above to say data.Data as that's what it was originally.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your code is not complete or the problem is that you are not defining any data in the DataSource nor where to get it from.

Your DataSource definition should be something like:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: MyData,
    schema: {
        data: function (d) {   
            console.log("data", d);
            return d.Data;
        }
    }
});
```

Where `MyData` is the data that you included in the original question (see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/YZEth/)

But you can simplify it and defining it as:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: MyData,
    schema: {
        data: "Data"
    }
});
```

See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/YZEth/1/

Comment: This helped immensely.  Thanks so much, the both of you.